# Seperating a nested array by matching value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a nested array which is like this:

```js
var data = [
              {floor: '2', id: '10002', label: 'Elutuba', items: Array(3)}
              {floor: '0', id: '10008', label: 'Saun', items: Array(2)},
              {floor: '0', id: '10010', label: 'test2', items: Array(2)},
              {floor: '0', id: '10011', label: 'test3', items: Array(2)}
          ]
```

From this array, i need to look through the matching floor values and create a arrays which matches and which doesn't. Like this:

```js
 var data2 = [
                {floor: '0', id: '10008', label: 'Saun', items: Array(2)},
                {floor: '0', id: '10010', label: 'test2', items: Array(2)},
                {floor: '0', id: '10011', label: 'test3', items: Array(2)}
            ]
var data3 = [{floor: '2', id: '10002', label: 'Elutuba', items: Array(3)}]
```

How can i do that?

Here's what i have tried :

```js
var newData = []
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
       return  newData.push(data[i].floor === data[j].floor);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Search for `groupBy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to get the results of all array, which have the same floor.

```js
var data = [{
    floor: '2',
    id: '10002',
    label: 'Elutuba',
    items: Array(3)
  }, {
    floor: '0',
    id: '10008',
    label: 'Saun',
    items: Array(2)
  },
  {
    floor: '0',
    id: '10010',
    label: 'test2',
    items: Array(2)
  },
  {
    floor: '0',
    id: '10011',
    label: 'test3',
    items: Array(2)
  }
]

const list = {};
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  if (!list[data[i].floor]) {
    list[data[i].floor] = [];
  }
  list[data[i].floor].push(data[i]);
}
console.log(list);
```

The first key is always the floor number. As you see, we have the key `0`, that gives you an array of all objects with the floor number 0 and there is also the key `2`, which gives you an array of a single object. That way you can add as much as object you want.

If you already know the floor number (for instance *2*) and you want to get that array only, you can use `list[2][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below, i don't know if it will meet your expectations

```js
var data2 = [
                {floor: '0', id: '10008', label: 'Saun', items: Array(2)},
                {floor: '2', id: '10010', label: 'test2', items: Array(2)},
                {floor: '0', id: '10011', label: 'test3', items: Array(2)}
            ]
var data3 = [{floor: '2', id: '10002', label: 'Elutuba', items: Array(3)}]


var newData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {

  const foundIndex = data3.findIndex( elt => elt.floor === data2[i].floor );
  
  if(foundIndex != -1){
  
    newData.push(data3[foundIndex]); // Here you can do some merge, i just take in data3
    
    data2.splice(i, 1);
    data3.splice(foundIndex, 1);
  }
  
 }
 
 console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a possible solution to your problem.

```js
const data2 = [
    {floor: '2', id: '10002', label: 'Elutuba', items: Array(3)},
    {floor: '0', id: '10008', label: 'Saun', items: Array(2)},
    {floor: '0', id: '10010', label: 'test2', items: Array(2)},
    {floor: '0', id: '10011', label: 'test3', items: Array(2)}
];

const data3 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
    if (data2[i].floor !== data2[i+1].floor) {
        data3.push(data2[i]);
        break;
    }
}

console.log(data3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your problem is about partitioning your array into two arrays and can be solved in multiple ways, once is use the [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?retiredLocale=it) method and check if every array's `curr` element satisfies your boolean condition `curr.floor === floor`  or not, so deciding in which of the two arrays put the element:

```js
const data = [
    {floor: '2', id: '10002', label: 'Elutuba', items: Array(3)},
    {floor: '0', id: '10008', label: 'Saun', items: Array(2)},
    {floor: '0', id: '10010', label: 'test2', items: Array(2)},
    {floor: '0', id: '10011', label: 'test3', items: Array(2)}
];

function groupBy(data, floor) {
    const result = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
        acc[(curr.floor === floor) ? 0 : 1].push(curr);
        return acc;
    }, [[], []]);

    return result;
}

console.log(groupBy(data, '0'));
```